# Compound primary key with autoincrement part

Tags: java, hsqldb

I'm using HSQLDB as DB engine. I want to create a table that has compound primary key. I use this code:

```
CREATE TABLE sample_table ( hash VARCHAR(20), 
id INTEGER, data VARCHAR(256), PRIMARY KEY(hash, id) )
```

But I need id to be autoincremental. I mean, that when I want to have something like this:

hash id data

---

abc  1  data_string_1
abc  2  data_string_2
efg  1  some_string_1
abc  3  some_data_again
efg  2  last_string

If I use this code:

```
CREATE TABLE sample_table ( hash VARCHAR(20), 
id INTEGER IDENTITY, data VARCHAR(256), PRIMARY KEY(hash, id) )
```

(So I make id an autoincremental primary key) An Exception is thrown:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: primary key already exist

What can I do to solve this problem?
As for me, using multiple queries with COUNT (id) and then increment this count and then insert new value is not good, I want HSQLDB to do it automatically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IDENTITY` implies a primary key.

But you can use a sequence to generate the ID without the need to declare it as an identity column:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE sample_sequence;
CREATE TABLE sample_table 
( 
  hash  VARCHAR(20), 
  id    INTEGER generated by default as sequence sample_sequence, 
  data  VARCHAR(256), 
  PRIMARY KEY(hash, id) 
);
```

Although I have to admit I fail to see the use-case behind this. If you auto-increment the ID, you can wind up with duplicate values for the `hash` column as the combination of both has to be unique, not just one of them.

Could it be that you want the `id` to actually **be** an `identity` (thus a PK) and another unique constraint only on the `hash` column - serving as a alternate key?

**Edit** (based on Fred's comment)

As an alternative you can use a slightly shorter version:

```
CREATE TABLE sample_table 
( 
  hash  VARCHAR(20), 
  id    INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY, 
  data  VARCHAR(256), 
  PRIMARY KEY(hash, id) 
);
```

Comment: Good answer, but you can use GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY instead of IDENTITY. The full definition does not imply a primary key.

Comment: Thank you, it works fine! @fredt, thank you too, it looks simplier

Comment: @fredt: thanks for clearing that up. This was not obvious to me from the manual.